# How to transfer the Firebase reference to another android activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

We have 2 Android activities (activity A and activity B)

Suppose that we instantiated a Firebase reference in activity A. Activity A also handles all user authentication (Facebook, Google, and email/password).

Activity B, which is started from activity A using an Android intent, should use the Firebase reference to access some data on the Firebase servers.

Now I was wondering what the best design is to send the Firebase ref from activity A to activity B.

1. Bundle the Firebase reference with the intent using Java Serializable and use intent.getExtra() in Activity B
2. Bundle the Firebase reference with the intent using Android Parcelable and use intent.getExtra() in activity B
3. Initiate the Firebase reference in a Android service and bind each activity to that service
4. Something else.

Comment: Why do you want to send firebase reference across activities ? How can that be useful to you? Post some relevant code too.

Comment: I will update my post with some relevant code when I get back from work.

Comment: Why do you want to send firebase reference across activities ? How can that be useful to you? 
In my main activity (Activity A) I have an image gallery of images stored in firebase. There you can add images, edit images, etc.
In my second activity (Activity B) you can use the same images to make a composite of the images in an Android surfaceview and save the composite to Firebase. But to add images to the surfaceview, Activity B also needs an image gallery (with different functionality compared to the gallery in Activity B). Thus Activity B also needs access to the Firebase DB. @ParagKadam

Comment: Create a new firebase reference in Activity B and access the firebase data using this reference. This wont incur any excess overhead.

Comment: That would be ideal. But what about the authentication. If the user is authenticated using the Firebase ref in Activity A, will he still be authenticated when using a different Firebase ref instance (instantiated in Activity B) ?

Comment: The firebase documentation say, "When a user authenticates, the default session length is 24 hours from initial authentication. This means that the user's authentication state will automatically be persisted between page loads. You can configure the session length by navigating to the Login & Auth section of your Firebase App Dashboard and configuring the Session Length dropdown on the top right. Every auth provider has an optional remember parameter".

Comment: So yes the authentication should persist. Give it a try and let me know if it does or does not.

Answer (score 3):

The common way to do this is to pass the URL for the data to the new activity. See for example [this method](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/drawing/BoardListActivity.java#L152-L159) from the [Firebase Android Drawing sample](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing):

```
private void openBoard(String key) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Opening board "+key);
    Toast.makeText(BoardListActivity.this, "Opening board: "+key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrawingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FIREBASE_URL", FIREBASE_URL);
    intent.putExtra("BOARD_ID", key);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The new activity then reads the URL and constructs a new `Firebase` reference:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String url = intent.getStringExtra("FIREBASE_URL");
    final String boardId = intent.getStringExtra("BOARD_ID");
    Log.i(TAG, "Adding DrawingView on "+url+" for boardId "+boardId);
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
```

The authentication state is indeed maintained between these calls. The Firebase SDK maintains a single connection to the server for an application session and each `Firebase` reference is a lightweight reference on top of that.

Comment: Addendum - Since I wasn't able to use Firebase() (not available), instead, I retrieved already created firebase instance (in Main Activity),
`FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("Firebase");` and then created a new reference `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp).getReference(NEW_URL);`