# Firebase Android Guidance for fetching data

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, android-sqlite

Recently I stored data on firebase by converting excel file data into .json and then importing it into firebase database. I don't know how I should proceed with below problem-

How to store data in Sqlite such that it checks firebase only if new data is available. For example- when new user opens the app, it fetches the data and stores all data in sqlite database. When he opens app again, it checks in splash screen if same data is available on firebase, then it won't store in sqlite. If some new data available, append to Sqlite. How should I proceed with this? If any other best way also commment.

If my approach is right. Can you guide me in using the approach. I m new.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase can persist the data itself locally.

You can enable disk persistence with just one line of code.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Do you really need to store the data in another sqlite database?

Comment: I want to use the list of data in other activity.

Comment: There is an answer to that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586309/how-to-transfer-the-firebase-reference-to-another-android-activity Does this help you?